# c# Unity - Mutiplayer interacting with objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, game-engine, multiplayer

```
  using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class Interactable : NetworkBehaviour {

    public float radius = 2f;
    bool isFocus = false;
    Transform player;
    bool hasInteracted = false;
    public Transform interactionPoint;



    public virtual void Interact()
    {
        // This method is meant to be overwritten
        Debug.Log("Interacting with " + transform.name);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (isFocus && !hasInteracted)
        {

            float distance = Vector3.Distance(player.position, interactionPoint.position);

             if(distance <= radius)
            {
                Interact();
                hasInteracted = true;

            }


        }


    }

    public void onFocused(Transform Player)
    {
        isFocus = true;
        player = Player;
    }

    public void onDeFocused()
    {
        isFocus = false;
        player = null;
        hasInteracted = false;


    }
    private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.yellow;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, radius);

    }

}
```

This is for the interaction which is overwritten.

```
 using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.Networking;


public class SphereBehaviour : Interactable {

    public float countdown = 1;
    public float timeLeft = 5f;



    public override void Interact()
    {
        Debug.Log("Interacting with the Sphere object");
        StartCoroutine(StartCountdown());


    }

    public IEnumerator StartCountdown() // Countdown from 5
    {
        countdown = timeLeft;
        while (countdown > 0)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
            countdown--;
        }

    }
```

The Problem is that this isn't networked and I can't think of the logic to do it. An Interface won't work or anything. Is there any possible solution which doesn't require changing everything?

I'm just trying to turn Brackeys set of youtube tutorials to something multiplayer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using the public "countdown" variable for some UI element.

1. If you want each player to see their own countdown when they themselves touch this Sphere, this should work fine.
2. If anyone touching the sphere should trigger a countdown for everyone, then this will have to be done differently. You'll want the host/server to track interactions between players and spheres, then trigger the countdown coroutine in the clients.

I personally don't recommend #1 in any case, as collisions/interactions should be done server-side.